# How do I show that for an open, nonempty subset $A$ of a topological vector space $V$ is convex?

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-spaces, convex-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I'm trying to prove the following:

> $V$ topological vector space. $A,B\subseteq V$ nonempty, open subsets. Suppose that a hyperplane $H\subseteq V$ separates $A$ and $B$. Show $H$ strictly separates $A$ and $B$ and $H$ is closed

I feel like I want to apply the theorem of isolation / separation theorem, which states

> If $A\subseteq V$ algebraically open, convex and $u\in V \backslash A$ $\Rightarrow \exists H $ affine hyperplane containing $u$ and strictly isolating $A$.

But honestly, I am very lost and have no clue where this is going, as my $A$ and $B$ are not convex and I cannot assume that $B\subset V\backslash A$,

Anybody that knows how I can approach this?

Cheers!

Comment: You're given that $H$ separates $A$ and $B$, so you only need to prove "strictly". Proceed by contradiction. If $H$ had a point in common with $A$ or with $B$, use that $A$ and $B$ are open to get points in $A$ or $B$ on the wrong side of $H$.

Comment: @andre I've thought of this, but i dont really know how to work with open in the general sence, only in the 'ball of points within $\varepsilon$ distance' sence. how do I work around that?

Comment: last comment was ment to say @AndreasBlass but i hit enter

Comment: (1) You'll need to use that a hyperplane is the inverse image, under a continuous (affine) function $f$, of $\{0\}$, and that the values of $f$ on opposite sides of the hyperplane have opposite signs. (2) You should learn to work with open in the general sense (i.e., learn some general topology) before trying to study topological vector spaces. The former is a prerequisite for the latter.